# Reason for stepped pins on M12 circular connector

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, soldering, through-hole

I've been looking at M12 circular connectors for a project I'm working on (for example [this one](https://www.digikey.co.nz/product-detail/en/amphenol-ltw/M12A-05PFFP-SF8002/1754-1013-ND/7102617), [drawing here](http://www.amphenolltw.com/2012download/2D%20PDF/03_M%20Series%20Sensor%20Connectors/M12A-XXPFFP-SF8XXX.pdf)), and I've noticed that many/all of them have stepped pins that create a 3mm or so offset/gap between the connector and PCB once soldered in place as per the datasheet/drawing. What is the reason for this?

A secondary question is, is there any reason not to make the holes in the PCB bigger to make the part flush, allowing for a stronger joint and higher rigidity without the gap? I've been looking around but can't find anything explaining why it's there.

Comment: Passing the whole pin through the PCB will make the PCB weaker, reduce clearance between traces / make it harder to escape, and allow an angle to form such the the connector isn't perfectly parallel.